# How to wrap text around image in div?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, word-wrap

I have problem with my composition of the webpage. Next div shows me my box with text and image, but text doesn't wrap the image. How can I solve that?

```css
#boxx {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font: 2em Calibri;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  display: block;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Чехов</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Антон Павлович Чехов</h2>
  <div id="boxx">Антон Павлович Чехов (17 [29] Січень 1860 — 2 [15] липня 1904) — російський письменник, загальновизнаний класик світової літератури. За професією лікар.</div>

  <img src="1.jpg" alt="Chehov">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can u brief? what's your expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for one you need to have it in the same container as your text (`#boxx`). You can't use 
`position: fixed`. `fixed` and `absolute` positions remove the element from the flow of the document which means they will not adhere to the other elements around them. You can set the `img` to `float:left` at that point:

HTML

```
<h2 style="text-align: center">Антон Павлович Чехов</h2>
<div id="boxx">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="Chehov">
    Антон Павлович Чехов (17 [29] Січень 1860 — 2 [15] липня 1904) — російський письменник, загальновизнаний класик світової літератури. За професією лікар.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#boxx{
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font: 2em Calibri;
  width:500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

img{ 
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 7px; 
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L794n2w9/)

Answer (score 1):

just add `float:left` to the image to get the result

**CSS**

```
#boxx img{
    float:left;
}
```